# Retrieve Similar Objects by Tags in Django

Tags: python, django

In the book Django 3 by Example (Chapter 2), the author suggests the following to retrieve posts similar to '*current post*' based on tags (via the taggit module).

```
post_tags_ids = post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tags_ids).exclude(id=post.id)
similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags')).order_by('-same_tags','-publish')[:4]
```

I understand the flow:

1. Get a list of all the IDs for the tags in the current post.
2. Filter all posts basis the list derived above, and exclude the current post.
3. Add a calculated field to the posts derived above that specify the number of tags they have in 'common' with current post. For example, if current post has tags 'one' and 'two', and another post has 'two' and 'three', the calculated field should be same_tags = 1 (i.e. 'two')

Here's where I am confused:

1. In point 2 above, will I get a QuerySet that has duplicate posts. For example, if a post has 2 tags in common with the current post, will the resulting QuerySet have 2 instances of the post? I tried this in shell, and this is what it seems to return. For example, if post has two tags in common with current post, it will be included twice. But I am not sure why this should be the case.
2. In point 3 above, how does Count('tags') calculate the number of 'common' tags between the post and current post? Shouldn't it just return the a count of the total number of 'tags' for the post in consideration? For example, if current post has tags 'one' and 'two', and another post has 'two' and 'three', the calculated field for the other post should just be same_tags = 2 (i.e. count of 'two', 'three').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, if post has two tags in common with current post, it will be included twice. But I am not sure why this should be the case.

No, you annotate with the related object, so that means that Django will make use of a `GROUP BY` clause.

> how does Count('tags') calculate the number of 'common' tags between the post and current post?

**No**, since you first have filtered the related tags with `tags__in=post_tag_ids`, it will only retain the tags that are the tags of your object.

It makes however more sense to implement this as:

```
similar_posts = Post.published.exclude(pk=post.pk).filter(
    tags__post=post
).annotate(
    same_tags=Count('tags')
).order_by('-same_tags','-publish')[:4]
```

Comment: "No, you annotate with the related object, so that means that Django will make use of a GROUP BY clause" - Not sure what I am doing wrong, but Point 2 above does seem to return duplicates for me. On your second point, "tags__in= post_tag_ids" returns a list of posts and not tags; so surely the post objects will retain all tags and not just the tags you filtered for with 'tags__in'?

Comment: @Rishi: there was a typo, it is `tags__post=post`.

Comment: @Rishi: it will not retain all tags, since we *filter* the `tags` with `tags__post=post`. We thus only retain the tags that at least are tags of `post`.

Comment: Apologies if this is too basic, but "similar_posts = Post.published.exclude(pk=post.pk).filter(tags__post=post)" - for a manytomany relationship, won't this return all posts filtered for tags that are present in current post. These resulting posts could have other tags and the QuerySet that gets returned will include these tags as well? And hence, wouldn't Count('tags') also include these other 'irrelevant' tags?

Comment: @Rishi: *no*, as the [documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses): "*When an annotate() clause is applied to a query, the annotation is computed over the state of the query up to the point where the annotation is requested. The practical implication of this is that filter() and annotate() are not commutative operations.*". The documentation that explains if you filter a related model, the annotation will span over the *filtered* related model.

Comment: As the example explains `Publisher.objects.filter(book__rating__gt=3.0).annotate(num_books=Count('book'))`, will count the number of related books with a rating greater than 3.

Comment: A filter clause *before* the annotate has thus effect on the annotation. It will make a LEFT OUTER JOIN, and filter that JOIN, and then calculate an aggregate on the *filtered* table.

Comment: Thanks a ton for responding. This clarifies. Big help!